# What is the the result of this PL/SQL code to cast a null?

Tags: plsql

I'm studying this PL/SQL code, andd I see this strange statement:

```
    CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(20))
...

    CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP(6))
```

hOW can Null be cast to timestamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any PL/SQL datatype (including primitive: date, number, binary_double, etc.) may have value of `NULL`, these are different values.
That behavior is opposite to Java approach to introduce null value as "empty reference" of special "null"-type :-)